# How to use a .NET assembly in a project with a different version than the one referenced by a third party?

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-assembly

Here's my scenario:

I have a project where it uses a third party assembly which in turn have references to several other assemblies.

```
Third party -+--> Assembly A 1.0.0.0
             +--> Assembly B 3.9.0.0
```

However, in my project I want to use a newer version of assembly A (2.3.0.0)
The problem is since assembly A have the same name, only one can exists in bin\release

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the third party library to continue using the old version, while you use the new version for a different purpose?

Comment: The GAC was designed to solve that problem.

Comment: Are you asking to run two different versions at the same time or do you want to just replace the old version with the new version?

Comment: @MarkByers - Yes I want the third party to continue using the old version.

Comment: @HansPassant - The assemblies are not strong named.

Comment: @Robert - Two versions at the same time but not from the same root assembly.

Comment: Do not accept 3rd party assemblies that are not strong named, that's criminal negligence given how easy it is to do.  Just renaming the 2nd DLL would be another workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant - The 3rd party is open source.

Comment: If the 3rd Party is open source you could get the source and strong name it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it the only way to have two versions of the same assembly loaded into one process is to load each one into a different AppDomain.

I haven't done this in practice so you'll need to experiment.